# Getting the data in SOAP response using XmlHttp

Tags: soap, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I'm using XhmHttp request object to send SOAP request to web services from classic asp page. The web service is returning xml string as result how can I read the xml string result from the SOAP response. Is there any property or method in the XmlHttp object supports that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vb example:

```
Dim xmlhttp As New Msxml2.XMLHTTP30

xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://localhost/books.xml", False

xmlhttp.send

MsgBox xmlhttp.responseXML.xml
```

have a look at the description

[responseXML Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the regular XMLDOM object to do the whole thing. You just 'load' the document right from the URL of the web service you're talking to.

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async=false
xmlDoc.load("http://server.domain.com/yourservice.asp?arg1=a")
```

Then you just continue parsing the document as if you had loaded it up from a local file.